# ¿Como hacer una conexion a MySql?

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion que inserte una hoja de excel a una tabla en MySQL, la aplicacion esta insertando bien los datos, pero el error esta que despues de insertar 149 filas me sale este error "Se ha generado un error al establecer el enlace a la BD.De tipo:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptionsjdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up"
Me podrian ayudar a resolver ese problema
Este es el codigo de mi conexion :

```
 public class ConexionMySQL {

String db = "palp";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+ db+"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
String user = "root";
String pass = "123456";

public Connection Conectar(){
    Connection link = null;
    try{
        //Cargar el DRIVER de conexion con el
        //SGDB Mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //Creacion de un enlace hacia la base de datos
        link = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url,this.user, this.pass);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha generado un"
                + "error al establecer el enlace a la BD."
                + "De tipo: " + ex);
    }
    return link;
}
```

}

Comment: Necesitaría más código para evaluar tu problema, pero a simple vista por la descripción del problema y todo, creo que puede que se estén agotando las conexiones a tu servidor MySQL debido a que abres una conexión pero no la cierras (es decir, no llamas al método `Connection#close`). Tips para mejorar tu aplicación: 1) **siempre que dejas de usar una conexión a base de datos, cerrarla** (el más importante y que es una regla más que un tip), 2) cambiar la manera inocente de obtener la conexión a la base de datos por usar un pool de conexiones

Comment: 3) En lugar de usar múltiples conexiones para ir guardardo los registros de 1 a 1, es decir 1 conexión a base de datos por registro, lo mejor es usar 1 sola conexión a base de datos y trabajar con todo el bloque de información en esta operación. 4) Si vas a registrar/actualizar varios elementos al mismo tiempo, es mejor usar operaciones en batch que hacer las operaciones puntuales. 5) Usar transacciones para mantener tus operaciones a la base de datos. Puedes tener commits parciales para no tener mucha información por enviar al servidor y luego un commit de toda la operación.

Comment: No necesitas un método para eso. Si usas Java 7 o superior, puedes hacerlo con `try-with-resources`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar entonces no haciendo las multiples conexones y cerrando la conexion.

Answer (score 0):

necesitas la libreria de mysql, yo utilizo mysql-connect-java-3.1.12

```
public class Conexion{
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TU_BASE_DE_DATOS";
    String user = "TU_USUARIO";
    String pass = "TU_CLAVE";

    public Connection getConexion(){
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        return con;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al conectarse a la BD: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}


}
```

Comment: el compañero si establece conexión a su BD, el detalle que agota el numero de conexiones permitidas ya que al parecer no cierra una conexión cuando la usa.

Comment: Si muchas gracias por tu aporte, y si el error esta que no cierro la conexion